# How to add a GitHub Service to a repo programmatically?

Tags: git, api, github

I just discovered GitHub Services and I'm using one of them in a project for my internship. The problem is that my project is going to work with some different GitHub repos and I have to add that same GitHub Service to all of them. I know I can just leave to the user going to their repo and add the service by hand, but I was wondering if there's a way I can do it for them, programmatically.

Maybe with GitHub's API? I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

What is called **Services** in settings sections are **GitHub hooks** under the hood.

You can use the [API to create individual hooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook).